# Echo an file content in ajax

Tags: ajax, echo, alert

Hello I have used such code, How to echo an 'load.php' contenton alert?

"alert(\'Submitted: ech results of load file \');"

```
$.ajax({
                url : \'load.php\',
                data: \'inputField\',
                data: \'\',
                type: \'GET\',
                cache: \'false\',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    link.addClass(\'loading\');                 
                },
                success: function () {
                    link.removeClass(\'loading\');      
                    alert(\'Submitted\');
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `success()` function should take a `data` argument, ie. `success: function(data)`... then you can alert data:

```
success: function (data) {
    link.removeClass(\'loading\');      
    alert(data);
}
```